# Batch transform on a big npy file - error 413

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-sagemaker

I have this case where I try to make a batch transform on a very sizable npy file. The file contains a 3D array (3000, 100, 100) where each observation is one element along the first axis and has the dim (1, 100, 100) for a total of 3000 observations.

Now I worked with batch transform in the past and for .csv or .jsonlines files it is a relatively easy way with split_type='Line' in the transform method. However, when I try to pass the big npy file, it does not seem to work with split_type='Line'. It works without it on smaller files, and the batch transform is successful. The image I am using is a pytorch cpu one, and the code that works for smaller files is:

```
predictor = Transformer(model_name='testingdep3',
                        instance_count= 1,
                        instance_type= 'ml.m5.large',
                        strategy= "SingleRecord",
                        output_path= 's3://xxx/inferencetesting/output/',
                        accept= "application/x-npy")
```

```
predictor.transform(data='s3://xxx/inferencetesting/testdata111.npy',
                    content_type='application/x-npy',
                    # split_type='Line'
                   )
```

My input_fn and predict_fn functions are as follows:

```
def input_fn(request_body, content_type='application/x-npy'):
    return np.load(io.BytesIO(request_body), allow_pickle=True)
```

```
def predict_fn(input_object, model):
    predictions = model.predict(input_object)
    return predictions
```

The maximum acceptable payload is MaxPayloadInMB=6 for this specific image. I was thinking of different ways of approaching this problem, including:

- having multiple smaller .npy files in the data directory
- changing the npy file to a protobuf format and then changing my input_fn to account for that, as well as uncommenting the split_line argument with the RecordIO value

Is there really no way to actually feed a very big numpy file to a batch transform job so that it's split somehow by using the standard arguments split_type and/or strategy?